Continuity of the right shift
In the lecture we consider the right shift$$u:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow X$$ $$ t \mapsto f(\cdot -t)$$ for fixed $f \in X$. If we take for $X = (C^0_b,\Vert \cdot \Vert_\infty)$, hence the space of continuous bounded operators, the right shift is not continuous since we can consider a function that has thinning triangles with constant height in uniformly spaced directions $(-\infty, 0]$. The proof is mainly based on the fact that the infinite norm only sees the tips and not the surrounding area. Therefore, I wondered whether $u$ would be continuous if we were to consider $X = L^1(\mathbb{R})$ with the usual norm instead. This would make this counterexample impossible, as the functions must converge to 0 pointwise. I have already tried to prove it, but unfortunately I didn't get very far. I would therefore be very grateful for any help.

The finite linear combinations of indicator functions of intervals $[a,b]$ are dense in $L^1.$ The function $t\mapsto f(\cdot-t)$ is continuous for $f$ being an indicator function of $[a,b].$
